# class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist when I load context manually

Tags: java, spring, xml-configuration

I have the following webApp folder structure:

[image]

I want to load spring context manually.

I wrote the following code:

```
ApplicationContext app = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

When the code above invokes I see the folowing exception message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

How to rewrite my code to avoid this exception?

**P.S.**
I don't want to move my xml file.

**P.P.S.**

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
```

doesn't work too although in web.xml was written

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and it works

Comment: I need a bean from context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide this location

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The resource is resolved relative to the Servlet context path.

When you provide

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
```

you're telling Spring to find the given resource on the classpath. In your case, it probably isn't there (WEB-INF is not typically added to the classpath afaik).

Either add it to the classpath or move the `applicationContext.xml` file to a different location on the classpath and use that path in your constructor.

Comment: how to add path to classpath?

Comment: @gstackoverflow When you launch `java`, use the `-cp` option.

Comment: I run application approximately: **mvn clean install jetty:run**

Comment: @gstackoverflow I don't know how maven does it.